# Flutter Firestore query listeners overlapping when running in Firebase Emulators

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream, listener

I have a Flutter widget that listens to 2 Firestore queries:

```
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('items')
        .where('tags', arrayContains: 'foo')
        .snapshots()
        .listen(
            (items) => print('Got items from query 1: ${items.docs.length}'));

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('items')
        .snapshots()
        .listen(
            (items) => print('Got items from query 2: ${items.docs.length}'));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Example')));
  }
}
```

The widget is rendered directly in the `main.dart` file:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: ExampleWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's are the documents:

```
items:
  item#1:
    tags: ['foo']
  item#2:
    tags: ['foo']
  item#3:
    tags: ['bar']
```

When I run the app in production, I see the following log:

```
Got items from query 1: 2
Got items from query 2: 3
```

**When I run the app with Firebase Emulators**, I see the following log:

```
Got items from query 1: 2
Got items from query 2: 2
Got items from query 2: 3
```

I'm expecting each query to receive exactly one event for 2 and 3 matched items respectfuly (like when running in prod). Why is the listener for the 2nd query executed twice?

Comment: are you able to reproduce the problem with _only_ this code? are there multiple instances of this widget being called? also, you are using `.listen`: are there more documents beign added?

Comment: @MendelG 
- No, this is just the minimum amount of code that I could come up with that is producing this problem. The original scenario is much more complex (list of items and a counter badge)

- no, this widget is passed directly to the `MaterialApp`

- no, documents are added or updated after running the app. The logs that are posted in the question are produced when just running the app.

Comment: @MendelG I updated the question to include the full code.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce... Try addding a `print` statement in the begining of `initState`. See how many times it's getting called.

Comment: @MendelG The `initState` is only running once, but I'm noticing something else: the problem only occurs when I run the app with Firebase Emulators, in production it works just fine.

Comment: @MendelG I updated the question with more information

Comment: Does the data already exist? or are you inserting it after you begin listening? If the data already exists and you're simply adding a listener, then the behavior looks like a bug and I recommend you file an issue here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues

Comment: Follow this issue for more information: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind 2nd query receiving a duplicate response is Firestore local caching: the result of the 1st query is saved locally and is used as the first source of data for the 2nd query before the actual result arrives from the server. The reason the behaviour is different between emulator and production is latency, here is the sequence of events for each:

```
Emulator:
1. query 1 is executed
2. result from query 1 is received (2) immediately and saved into cache
3. query 2 is executed
4. query 2 uses the result from cache (2)
5. query 2 receives the correct result (3) from the server
```

```
Production:
1. query 1 is executed
3. query 2 is executed
4. result from query 1 is received (2) and saved into cache
5. result from query 2 is received (3) and saved into cache
```

More information can be found in these GH issues in the [flutterfire](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11460) and [firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7820) repos: